# PHP: extract string from other

Tags: php

I got this json from wikipedia search API:

```
["ah",["Ahbez, Eden","Ahadith","Ahern, Bertie","Ahmad Jannati","Ahmed Shah Durrani"]]
```

how to extract only content part:

```
["Ahbez, Eden","Ahadith","Ahern, Bertie","Ahmad Jannati","Ahmed Shah Durrani"]
```

thanks,

Comment: I'll give you an answer because it's so easy, but the guidelines clearly state you should show your effort. This is not a copy-paste solution site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a json string so parsing it shouldnt be a problem, if you just looked up how to parse json using php.

```
$array = json_decode($result,true);
$content = json_encode($array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use implode and select the right array index (I dont know the name of your array thatswhy I used $myArray.

```
$myArray = json_decode($myArray);
$content = implode(",", $myArray[1]);
```

Remember that this works only if your json formatted array always has the same structure.

Comment: For gods sake ok I forgot json_decode but you could give me the hint to fix it with a comment instead of a downvote.

Comment: Not the one who downvoted you but you keep writing `implode`, why? OP just needs the `$myArray[1]`, implode will return a raw string.

Comment: I think the author stated is question unclear. "Extract content" is getting the content out of the array for me. Ok I see now he posted the inner array element with [ and ] but thats still not 100% clear. I think we can provide both solutions and the OP can pick the way that suits him.

Comment: fair enough. I don't like either when OPs are just asking for something without relevant code.

Comment: i was the one that downvoted. I'll remove it, but your solution is still wrong ;-) Your implode returns a comma-seperated list of the strings, not a json array.

Comment: Thanks and as I said the op did not state wether he really wants a JSON array. It was just a guess so we cannot be sure if its right or wrong.